# regex expression to match and not match

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm using powershell and want to use regex to match something. I've got a list of servers that have this naming convention - `ABCPPsomename`.
So when regex finds `PP` in a name I want it included.

However some of the servers have the name `ABCPRODsomenAppame` and the match is including these servers becasue of the `App` in the name.

I need it so if the `PP` is in the name to include it and if it's not in the name to leave it out.
Also I need servers name that are `ABCPPsomeAppname` to be included

Comment: Have you at least tried something we can help you with? How do _you_ know that ABCPRODsomenAppame is not to be matched and ABCPPsomename is? Is it the location of the PP or the case of the text? Rules need to be established in order for solutions to be perfect for edge cases like AAPPsomename

Comment: I have added new code that may be more applicable in your case.

Answer (score 1):

IF (big **if** because you are not clear on this) all your servers start their name with the literal text `ABC`, then yes, it would not be hard to do:

```
$servers = @('ABCPPsomename', 'ABCPRODsomenAppame', 'ABCPPsomeAppname')
$servers | Where-Object { $_ -match '^ABCPP' }
```

Result

```
ABCPPsomename
ABCPPsomeAppname
```

---

**UPDATE**

---

From your latest comment, I gather that the servername convention should be 3 to a maximum of 5 characters to start with, followed by either `PP` or something totally different like `PROD`.

To find only the `"PP"` servers in the list, you might try this instead:

```
$servers = 'ABCPPsomename', 'ABCPRODsomenAppame', 'ABCPPsomeAppname'
$servers | Where-Object { $_ -match '^[A-Z]{3,5}PP' }
```

Result:

```
ABCPPsomename
ABCPPsomeAppname
```

Regex details:

```
^          Assert position at the beginning of the string
[A-Z]      Match a single character in the range between “A” and “Z”
   {3,5}   Between 3 and 5 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
PP         Match the characters “PP” literally
```

If you need the match to be case sensitive, use `-cmatch` instead.

Hope that helps

Comment: Yeah, there is a naming convention but engineers haven't adhered to it which is part of the problem. Some machines have four, five characters at the start.

Answer (score 1):

Note: This answers shows **how to match *case-sensitively***, which turned out not to be what the OP wanted.

---

It sounds like you want to match server names that contain *substring* `PP` *case-sensitively*, so that `PP` matches, but `App` doesn't, for instance.

For case-sensitive matching, use the `-cmatch` operator:

```
PS> 'PPOnly', 'OnlyApp', 'PPandApp', 'Neither' -cmatch 'PP'
PPOnly
PPandApp
```

More work is needed if the substring should only be matched at a certain position.

Note:

- The above command operates directly on an input *array* and returns the filtered array.
- If you want to filter via the *pipeline*, see [Theo's `Where-Object`-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53636369/45375).

Comment: +1 for the `-cmatch`. Also for the tip about dropping the `@(..)` on array literals. It's a hard habit to break though..

Comment: Thanks, @Theo. Understood re habit; I can also see the _visual_ appeal of using `@(...)`, and in v5.1+ you don't pay a performance penalty anymore. However, my vote is for  fewer chars. and spreading the word that `,` by itself is enough to construct arrays.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's not case sensitive though, would you be able to show me an example where it works without the case sensitive, please.

Comment: @RussellMaycock: I see. It looks like Theo's updated answer may have the solution. If you literally just want to ignore `App` matches - i.e., if you want to ignore `pp` if it is preceded by `a`, you can use: `'ABCPPsomeAppName', 'ABCPRODsomeAppname' -match '(?<!a)pp'`